# After installing a python package it still shows no module found

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install a package dicttoxml using pip install. After that I am trying to use that package from jupyter notebook.But it still shows 'no module named dicttxml'. Is it because ipython kernel is different from the regular python kernel that is used?Also I am using a anaconda environment which same as of the installation. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Did you install the library in a virtual environment?

Comment: @Sashaank No I have used pip install after activating the anconda environment. I have not used virtual environment here.

Comment: _No I have used pip install after activating the anconda environment. I have not used virtual environment here._ Those sentences contradict each other, can you clarify things?

Comment: @AMC I mean I have not used any 'venv' here. But yes I have installed library in my required environment.

Comment: _I mean I have not used any 'venv' here._ Ah I see, yes that's true, since you're using Conda.